# Has anyone integrated CKAN with Qlik, Tableau, and R? How did you do it?

Tags: tableau-api, qlikview, ckan, catalog

I would like to know if anyone has created an environment where CKAN is the data catalog and it is integrated with data analysis and visualization tools like Qlik, Tableau, and R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For integration with Tableau, you can use Odata extension https://github.com/jqnatividad/ckanext-odata. This extension provides OData 3.0 endpoint which you can easily integrate into Tableau.

Answer (score 1):

In CKAN just set csv/excel export in scheduled interval.
Store export in network/cloud drive.
Then just set reload schedule in qlikview in which it loads that data.

Comment: Thank you very much Hubert. Do you think qlikview or tableau could be integrated into CKAN? The user would have access to qlikview or tableau within the CKAN environment?

Comment: Have no idea :-)